# How to send the assertion failure message to the console using QUnitJS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit, console.log, assertion

Here is an example from QUnit's [website](https://api.qunitjs.com/equal/)

```
QUnit.test( "equal test", function( assert ) {
  assert.equal( 0, 0, "Zero, Zero; equal succeeds" );
  assert.equal( 0, 1, "Zero, Zero; equal succeeds" );

});
```

I just want the message to be printed out to console like console.assert. How can I do this? If this is not possible with QUnit, is there something else that could achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is browserify bundled version of tape (https://wzrd.in/standalone/tape@latest) that seems to work the way I want.
Here is an example: https://jsbin.com/dobefu/edit?html,js,output